# Worpitzky's identity eulerian number - formula demonstration

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, eulerian-numbers

Can someone tell me please how am I supposed to demonstrate the Worpitzky's identity :

$$
x^{n}=\sum_{k}\left\langle\begin{array}{l}
n \\
k
\end{array}\right\rangle\left(\begin{array}{c}
x+k \\
n
\end{array}\right)
$$

Comment: Induction & use the recurrence relation for Eulerian numbers. Good luck $ \ddot \smile$

Comment: What have you tried? And: how do you define Eulerian numbers? (There are different definitions.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exercise 6.14 in *Concrete Mathematics* suggests to use induction on $n$ and the following identity:
$$x\binom{x+k}{n} = (k+1)\binom{x+k}{n+1} + (n-k)\binom{x+k+1}{n+1}$$